# Regex for only characters 0-9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to find/utilize a regex for only the characters 0-9. If possible, I'm also trying to enable the user to utilize their normal keys (backspace, left and right arrows, backspace).

In addition, I want to stop . (periods), % (percentages), and ' (single quotes).

This is what I have so far, but it is not stopping the above three issues:

```
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode( key );
        var regex = /[0-9]/;
        //alert(theEvent.keyCode)
        if( !regex.test(key) && theEvent.keyCode!='8' && theEvent.keyCode!='46'&& theEvent.keyCode!='37' && theEvent.keyCode!='39') {//keyCode8 = backspace
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: something is seriously wrong with your UX if you have to do this.

Comment: is this bound to a keypress, keyup, or keydown handler?

Comment: You're sending mixed signals. The title says "1 to 9", but the question says "0-9", which is it?

Comment: Your title conflicts with the first line of your question

Comment: Also your regexp should be `/^[0-9]$/` (it says, "starts and ends with digits only")

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I'm looking for 0-9.

Comment: @h3nr1x, no it says, string contains only a single digit

Comment: @m.buettner Yes a typo there, my bad, should be `/^[0-9]*$/`, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @h3nr1x `/^[0-9]*$/` doesnt make sense cuz he is going to match only a `single character`..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `||` instead of `&&`

You can also use the regex`[^.%']`.it matches any character except `.`,`%`,`'`

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array of allowed keyCodes and check against that:

```
function onlyNumbers(evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;

    // 0-9, backspace, left and right arrows
    var allowedKeyCodes = [48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,8,37,39]; 

    if(allowedKeyCodes.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```